# How do I use regex to return a line but not including the expression?

Tags: regex

I have some data that has descriptive information before and after the text that I want to keep. I want to use regex (or anything that will work) to return only the text in the middle but that text varies wildly so it would be hard to regex itself

I've tried to look online but nothing seems to do what I want it to do. Unless I'm misunderstanding negative lookbehind and lookahead that doesn't seem to do what I want

```
<sms protocol="0" address="" date="" type="1" subject="null" body="Hi" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="" sub_id="1" readable_date="" contact_name="" />
```

I only want to body of this line. So I only want it to return the word "Hi"

Comment: If this text is actually XML, you want an XML parser, not a regex.

Comment: What tool or language do you use? See the description of the regex tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract `body` only, this Js regex will work (should be fine for php as well).

```
/(?<=body=").+(?=" toa)/
```

Works assuming that `toa` property will always follow `body`. And this

```
/(?<=body=").+?(?=")/
```

works regardless of property order but assumes that your text doesn't contain `"`.

Answer (score -1):

The body value is in capture group 2.
This will match tags that are not self contained as well.
If you want to match tags that are *only* self contained ( `<sms../>` ), let me know.

`<sms(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sbody\s*=\s*(['"])([\S\s]*?)\1)\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>`

https://regex101.com/r/EOLXW8/1

Explained

```
                        # Begin sms tag
 < sms
 (?= \s )
 (?=                    # Asserttion (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s body \s* = \s*      # Body attribute
      ( ['"] )               # (1), Quote
      ( [\S\s]*? )           # (2), Body value
      \1 
 )
                        # Have the body value, just match the rest of tag
 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+

 >                      # End  tag
```